# How do I deploy REST API using an imported array of JS objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, serverless

I've been following [this article](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/) to deploy a Node REST API to AWS and I've hit a wall. I've set up my `serverless.yml` to configure the AWS REST API. As you can see it accounts for this and a DynamoDB table.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local

service: pair-api

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["wineTable", "Arn"] }
  environment:
    WINE_TABLE: wineTable

resources: # CloudFormation template syntax
  Resources:
    wineTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: wineTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: name
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: name
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /pair/wine
      - http: "ANY {proxy+}"
```

My `index.js` file (below) is supposed to populate this endpoint with an array of JS objects. For some reason, when I set `message` to `test` (see below), I get the error message "Internal Service Error".

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

import * as test from "./db/test";

app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict: false }));

app.get("/pair/wine", function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    success: "true",
    message: test
  });
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

When I set message to a JavaScript object, (see below), my AWS API end point returns the correct message.

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

import * as test from "./db/test";

app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict: false }));

app.get("/pair/wine", function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    success: "true",
    message: [{
      "test": true,
      "testing": "Test"
    }]
  });
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

What is the correct way of setting the `GET` request for an AWS API so it returns an array of JS objects? I've tried importing JS files a few different ways (see below), but nothing seems to work;

```
import * as test from "./db/test";
import test from "./db/test";
const test = require("./db/test");
```

Comment: Update: importing the JS object in `index.js` seems to trigger "Internal service error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to read up on importing modules in Node, which leverages ES5 require statements instead of import.